# Cómo combinar varias funciones js usando hooks

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un problema con una al momento de ejecutar 2 funciones en un onChange de react, Así funciona.

```html
<div class="col-auto form-group">
    <label>Saludo</label>
    <div className="input-group">
       <div className="input-group-prepend col-md-2 col-sm-3">
           <div id="divUno" className="input-group-text">5%</div>
       </div>
       <select onChange={(e) => { calcularTotal(e.target.value, 5, false, 'divUno', 'Total_enc', 'Total_Ec', 'final'); }} className="form-control form-select  col-md-10 col-sm-9 " id="divUno" name="divUno" required="true">
           <option value="1">CUMPLE</option>
           <option value="0">NO CUMPLE</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Realmente es un monitoreo de calidad, en donde si dices que no, baja automáticamente el valor y además se colorea rojo. Del mismo modo viceversa. Adjunto el script:

```
var resultadoFinal = 100;
var resultadoEnc = 100;
var resultadoEc = 100;
function calcularTotal(value, porcentaje, method, idDivModificar, idTotal_enc, idTotal_Ec, idFinal, set) {
resultadoEc = (method == true && value == 1) ? 100 : (method == true && value == 0) ? 0 : resultadoEc;
resultadoEnc = (method == false && value == 1) ? resultadoEnc + porcentaje : (method == false && value == 0) ? resultadoEnc - porcentaje : resultadoEnc;
resultadoFinal = (resultadoEc == 0) ? 0 : resultadoEnc;

document.getElementById(idDivModificar).style.backgroundColor = value == 1 ? "#e9ecef" : "#dc3545"; //colorea gris si cumple o rojo si no lo es
document.getElementById(idDivModificar).style.color = value == 1 ? "#000" : "#fff"; //El texto es negro si cumple o si no blanco
document.getElementById(idDivModificar).innerHTML = value == 1 ? porcentaje + "%" : "0%"; //si cumple le concatena el porcentaje con % de lo contrario le muestra 0%

document.getElementById(idTotal_enc).value = resultadoEnc + '%';
document.getElementById(idTotal_Ec).value = resultadoEc + '%';
document.getElementById(idFinal).value = resultadoFinal + '%';
```

La cuestión es que hasta este punto funciona correctamente, pero necesito utilizar hooks, las 2 funciones separadas funcionan, pero juntas no. Ejemplo hook:

```html
<input className="form-control" type="text" name="tmo" id="tmo " onChange={(e) => { settmo(e.target.value) }} placeholder="00:00:00" />
<select onChange={(e) => { calcularTotal(e.target.value, 5, false, 'divUno', 'Total_enc', 'Total_Ec', 'final'); setuno(e.target.value) }} className="form-control form-select  col-md-10 col-sm-9 " id="divUno" name="divUno" required="true">
    <option value="1">CUMPLE</option>
    <option value="0">NO CUMPLE</option>
</select>
```

Espero haberme hecho entender. Adicionalmente quiero importar ese script personalizado desde otro archivo, pero no he encontrado lo he logrado.
Saludos...

Comment: Qué es lo que no funciona? Te recomiendo leer [ask]. Si estás usando reactjs por favor comparte el código de tu componente

Comment: No esta claro lo que estas tratando de hacer, el tu Ejemplo Hook, ambas funciones se llaman sin problemas en el `onChange`;  ¿ `calcularTotal`   depende del resultado de `setuno`? ¿O son dos procesos independientes? saludos

Comment: Pero quiero aprovechar la oportunidad para saber si el codigo lo puedo dejar en un archivo js externo, como un recurso que se puede reutilizar. No he encontrado la forma de importarlo y de llamar la función desde los input. Saludos...

Comment: Al final puse a leer la variable en el input y listo <input className="form-control" type="text" name="total_Ec" id="total_Ec" value={resultadoEc + "%"} readOnly /> Gracias